# I'm having problems with my procedures that were built in repl.it

Tags: python

I have been working on a school project for a week or so and I'm getting stuck whenever I try and build the procedure to simplify the code

I haven't yet tried to make the 3rd call because I would like to get the issues sorted out with the code first. I've been using repl.it to do all the work.

If you were to put the code into repl.it and try to run it you'll see that the procedure only runs choice  2 even when choice 1 is picked. and I get the error that the complexity is to high as well as other errors

```
import sys
import random
print (" 8888")
print("8    8")
print("8    8")
print(" 8888")
print("8    8")
print("8    8")
print(" 8888")


print("Hello, I am the 8 ball code, what is your name coder?")
name = input()
print("hello, " + name)

print ("Please make a choice  ")
print(" Enter 1 for Eight ball ")
print(" Enter 2 for guessing the number")
print(" Enter 3 to quit")
choice = input("")
print(choice)

def game_choice(game_number):
 if game_number == "1":
while ans:
 question = input("Ask the magic 8 ball code a question:  ")

answers = random.randint(1,8)

if question == "":
    sys.exit()

elif answers == 1:
    print ("It is certain")

elif answers == 2:
    print ("It is promising")

elif answers == 3:
    print ("You may rely on it")

elif answers == 4:
    print ("Ask again later")

elif answers == 5:
    print ("Concentrate and ask again")

elif answers == 6:
    print ("Your spelling was wrong, take an english class then ask again")

elif answers == 7:
    print ("My reply is no")

elif answers == 8:
    print ("My sources (which is me) say no")

elif answers == 9:
    print ("There may never be an answer to that")

elif answers == 10:
    print ("With everything going on, You shouldn't ask this")


elif game_number == "2":
 x = random.randint(1, 10)
guess = int(input("Enter a number from 1 to 10: "))
while x != "guess":
   print
   if guess < n:
     print ("guess is low")
     guess = int(input("Enter an number from 1 to 10: "))
elif guess > n:
    print ("guess is high")
    guess = int(input("Enter an number from 1 to 10: "))
else:
    print ("you guessed it! ")
    break
```

Comment: You have a bunch of indentation problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First, your 8-ball code can be massively simplified by using random.choice.

You can just say:

```
import random
answers=[] #enter your answers here
print (random.choice(answers))
```

Second, you have a lot of indentation problems, and stuff that doesn't really make sense to be there. What you can do is define functions to make your code more organized and easy to read to determine what your problem is. Here:

```
import sys
import random

def Eightball():
  inpt=input("Enter your question...")
  answers=[] #put your set of answers here
  print (random.choice(answers))

def guessingGame():
  num=random.randint(1,10)
  guesses=4
  for i in range (guesses):
    guess=input("What is your guess?")
    guess=int(guess)
    if guess>num:
      print ("Your guess is greater than my number.")
    elif guess<num:
      print ("Your guess is less than my number.")
    elif guess==num:
      print ("You win.")
      return
  print ('My number was {}'.format (num))


print ("Enter one to play eight ball")
print ("Enter two to play guessing game")
print ("Enter three to quit")
game_type=input ('')

if game_type==1:
  Eightball()
elif game_type==2:
  guessingGame()
elif game_type==3:
  sys.exit
```

Comment: For the project I am doing I need to have the 8 ball code in a while loop, my project needs to have a procedure that is being called and a loop as well as a list. The code you gave has helped a lot. I am still trying to figure it out but thank you

Comment: @rbs2002 Hi. In the while loop, all you have to do is.  instead of "for i in range(guesses)" , you can make a counter, and then the loop would be "while counter<guess:" Random.choice includes a list that you have to make, and a procedure is just a function, that is within the code provided.